# If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, show $Z(G)N/N \subset Z(G/N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

My notes claim that $Z(G)N/N = \{ zN \in G/N :[g,z] \in N \;\forall g \in G \}. ​$

It is clear to me that the right hand side is contained in $Z(G/N)$, however I cannot make sense of the equality to give me the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use that equality to get the result.  If $gnN$ is an element of $Z(G)N/N$, where $g \in Z(G)$ and $n \in N$, then for any element $xN \in G/N$, where $x \in G$, you have

$$(gnN)(xN) = (gN)(xN) = gxN = xgN = (xN)(gN) = (xN)(gnN).$$

This shows that $gnN$ commutes with an arbitrary element of $G/N$, so it lies in the center $Z(G/N)$ of $G/N$.

**Remark**: If $X$ is any subset of $G$, then $X/N$ is by definition the set of cosets of the form $xN$, where $x \in N$.  Clearly $Z(G)N/N = Z(G)/N$.  So a typical element of $Z(G)N/N$ is just $gN$, for $g \in Z(G)$.

Comment: With all respect: your remark is wrong: if $X$ is any subset of $G$, then the canonical image $XN/N$ is the set of cosets of the form $xN, x \in X$. Not $X/N$. Also *Clearly $Z(G)N/N=Z(G)/N$* is therefore wrong.

Comment: For a subset $X$ of $G$, in what sense is $XN/N$ or $X/N$ defined? $N$ may not be contained in $XN$ (or $X$). What would the cosets in $X/N$ look like, if not $xN, x \in X$ ?

Comment: You just gave the answer yourself.  $X/N$ is literally the set of cosets of the form $xN$, where $x$ ranges through the elements of $X$.  This makes sense even if $N$ is not contained in $X$.  If $H$ is any subgroup of $G$ whatsoever, then $H/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$, equal to $HN/N$.

Answer (score 1):

Additional remark: equality in $Z(G)N/N \subseteq Z(G/N)$ does not have to occur, take for example $G=Q$, the quaternion group of order $8$ and $N=Z(G)$. Then $Z(G)N/N=\overline{1}$, and $Z(G/N) \cong C_2 \times C_2$.

However, in general, if $N \cap G'=1$, then $Z(G/N)=Z(G)N/N=Z(G)/N$: if $g \in G, n \in N$, then $[n,g]=n^{-1}(g^{-1}ng) \in N \cap G'$. So $N \subseteq Z(G)$ in this case. If $Z(G/N)=K/N$, then $[K,G] \subseteq N$, but also $[K,G] \subseteq [G,G]$, hence $[K,G]=1$, that is $K \subseteq Z(G)$. So $Z(G/N) \subseteq Z(G)/N$ and the reverse inclusion was already proven by @D_S.